# Add top category to .json array with Notepad++

Tags: arrays, json, notepad++

i have an array that right now sort of looks like this, listing only the answer to a question and its value.

```
{
"answer": "sample answer number 1"
"value": 1
},
```

But now i need the array to have two more supercategories:

A questioncategory to differentiate between several types of questions

And the question itself

```
{
"questioncategory": "sample questioncategory"
"question": "sample question?"
"answer": "sample answer number 1"
"value": 1
}
```

Issue: How can i add these two extra lines to each without having to manually paste these lines infront of the already existing lines?

The category and question is always the same, only the answers are individual.
This script is used for a Treemap.

I use Notepad++

Comment: (By your keyboard button press). what does this question mean for ?

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand what the OP want. What language are you using ?

Comment: @SolidBox even i didn't understand your question

Comment: i overhauled the phrasing, sorry i'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++

```
[{
"answer": "sample answer number 1",
"value": 1
},
{
"answer": "sample answer number 2",
"value": 2
}]
```

Use replace: Search/Replace (Ctrl-H)

Find : "answer"

Replace with: "category": "sample category",\n"question": "sample question?",\n"answer"

Search mode: Extended

And it should output:

```
[{
"category": "sample category",
"question": "sample question?",
"answer": "sample answer number 1",
"value": 1
},
{
"category": "sample category",
"question": "sample question?",
"answer": "sample answer number 2",
"value": 2
}]
```

[image: ---Look at it]